# Sharepoint Online force same filename to overwrite existing file in variable folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload

On Sharepoint Online, I have uploaded 300K files into 35 DocLibs with subfolders named using the original year of the ReleaseDate (to mitigate the 5000 item view threshold). ReleaseDate.Year has been immutable for decades here... but...

A new external process now resets ReleaseDate for each revision of a document, changing the ReleaseDate.Year to the current year.

Now our document revisions are uploading to the current year folder rather than overwriting the original document in it's original year folder location, as required.

We need to find a way to overwrite the existing file by the same name in original folder location, despite the new ReleaseDate...

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your users may be choosing the folder/location that they are saving to erroneously. If you point to the file in the original year folder, it will ask you if you want to overwrite it, when choosing Save As... from Office.